# R prediction interval for the mean of the new sample

Tags: r, prediction

Given a regression model created from one dataset, I have been using WinBUGS to construct prediction intervals (PIs) around the mean of a second dataset. I have just discovered the "predict" function in R, but it delivers PIs around each predicted value in the second dataset. I have searched the R help, here and on the Net and only found the intervals for the separate members.

The average of the these intervals is clearly not the same as the PI around the predicted sample mean (and I have tested that against the value I got from WinBUGS).

How do I get R to give me the PI around the mean?

Comment: What kind of model? Example code used to fit the model in R?

Comment: I'm using straight linear regression with several indep vars as well as log-log regression to give a relationsjip of y=ax^b. The code for the first case is:

Comment: Sorry, not used to this process and not at the PC which has the code but from memory:
zmodel<-lm(Mass~Diameter+Height+Width,data=dataset1) then 
pred_int<-predict(zmodel,dataset2)
"pred_int" contains PIs for each element in dataset2

Answer (score 0):

There used to be an R `mean.data.frame` function, but it was deprecated and then removed. You can get the same result with:

```
  mean.vec <-  lapply(na.omit(dfrm), mean)
```

Then probably just:

```
 predict(fit, newdata=data.frame(mean.vec) )
```

I say 'probably' because you provided no dataset to test this with and provision of such is in my opinion your responsibility. I have no idea whether this replicates the JMP method or the WinBUGS method.

Comment: Thanks, DWin. I'll check that out and give it a go. I'm glad you can see my ref to JMP because it's gone from my screen - but that could be user error. I'm new to using this - or any - forum. Regards, Peter

Comment: DWin, Thanks for your suggestion. I have had a look at your suggested code and I believe it is not the answer. The "lapply" statement returns a vector of the means of each column in the dataframe. Supplying that to "predict" returns the PI around a single entity, which happens to consist of those means. What I would desperately like to be able to do in R is to obtain a PI which is (95%) likely to contain the mean predicted response, given a new dataset of n items. This is what JMP and WinBUGS allow me to do. (Note: it is not the mean of the n individual PIs.) Regards, Peter

Comment: Then it might be `mean(predict(fit, newdata=dfrm))+ c(-1.96,1.96) * sd(predict(fit, newdata=dfrm))`. (We are not JMP users around here and only a very few of us have been WinBUGS users.) The issue of whether these are pseudo-CI's or pseudo-PI's remains open.

Comment: Also note: The above suggestion assumes a fairly large sample and that the "group-PI" should be even wider for small samples, since the t-statistic should be higher and the SD would be multiplied by `sqrt(1+1/n)`. (You still have not provided any data or even a good description of what the task really looks like.)